# Google Maps realtime gps tracker

Tags: google-maps, gps

Hi I've been working on this realtime gps tracker but I can't get beyond an error, I think it has something to do with making "map" a global variable .
What happens is, I am using gps cordinates that are loaded via ajax from an xml file and parsed into an array, but it seems I can't display the markers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
 <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    </style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Network Monitor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      1: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      0: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

   //global array to store our markers
var markersArray = [];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.80815648152641, 140.95355987548828),
            zoom : 13,
            mapTypeId : 'roadmap'
        });
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;



    function load() {
        

        // your first call to get & process inital data
 downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML); 

    }

    function processXML(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        //clear markers before you start drawing new ones
        resetMarkers(markersArray)
        for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var host = markers[i].getAttribute("host");
            var type = markers[i].getAttribute("active");
            var lastupdate = markers[i].getAttribute("lastupdate");
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var html = "<b>" + "Host: </b>" + host + "<br>" + "<b>Last Updated: </b>" + lastupdate + "<br>";
            var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map : map,
                position : point,
                icon : icon.icon,
                shadow : icon.shadow
            });
            //store marker object in a new array
            markersArray.push(marker);
            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);


        }
            // set timeout after you finished processing & displaying the first lot of markers. Rember that requests on the server can take some time to complete. SO you want to make another one
            // only when the first one is completed.
            setTimeout(function() {
                downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML(data));
            }, 5000);
    }

//clear existing markers from the map
function resetMarkers(arr){
    for (var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
        arr[i].setMap(null);

    }
    //reset the main marker array for the next call
    arr=[];
}
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState == 4) {
                request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
    }
    function doNothing() {}
 

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

My php sid works well.
With this response.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><markers><marker host="192.168.1.1" lastupdate="2012-03-12 18:02:54" lat="37.805538" lng="140.967235" active="1"/><marker host="192.168.1.80" lastupdate="2012-03-09 15:02:03" lat="37.805450" lng="140.967224" active="0"/><marker host="192.168.1.2" lastupdate="2012-03-12 18:03:30" lat="37.805685" lng="140.967224" active="1"/><marker host="192.168.1.75" lastupdate="2012-03-12 18:05:14" lat="37.805685" lng="140.967150" active="0"/><marker host="192.168.1.67" lastupdate="2012-03-12 18:07:04" lat="37.805685" lng="140.966995" active="1"/></markers>
```

But on the html side I receive this error

```html
InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working with this code :-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
</style>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Network Monitor</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var customIcons = {
1: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
},
0: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
}
};
//global array to store our markers
var markersArray = [];
var map;
var infoWindow;
function load() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center : new google.maps.LatLng(37.80815648152641, 140.95355987548828),
zoom : 13,
mapTypeId : 'roadmap'
});
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
// your first call to get & process inital data
downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML);
}
function processXML(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
//clear markers before you start drawing new ones
resetMarkers(markersArray)
for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var host = markers[i].getAttribute("host");
var type = markers[i].getAttribute("active");
var lastupdate = markers[i].getAttribute("lastupdate");
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
var html = "<b>" + "Host: </b>" + host + "<br>" + "<b>Last Updated: </b>" + lastupdate + "<br>";
var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map : map,
position : point,
icon : icon.icon,
shadow : icon.shadow
});
//store marker object in a new array
markersArray.push(marker);
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
// set timeout after you finished processing & displaying the first lot of markers. Rember that requests on the server can take some time to complete. SO you want to make another one
// only when the first one is completed.
setTimeout(function() {
downloadUrl("nwmxml.php", processXML(data));
}, 5000);
}
//clear existing markers from the map
function resetMarkers(arr){
for (var i=0;i<arr.length; i++){
arr[i].setMap(null);
}
//reset the main marker array for the next call
arr=[];
}
function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
}
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest;
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if(request.readyState == 4) {
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
callback(request, request.status);
}
};
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}
function doNothing() {}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

now the only problem is it doesn't update the positions with this error :-

```html
realtim...ng.html (line 102)
TypeError: callback is not a function
callback(request, request.status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Google supports many of the real-time GPS tracking systems. So, it is easy for you to track your kid's location, find your smartphone using ADM and other applications are there which can be used to track and get the exact location of your device or child. Mysecurekid comes up with many features that allows parental control and get to connect with their child anytime, anywhere and notifies the parent when their child goes out of the marked location or entering into a dangerous location. It is **[Best GPS tracker smartwatch](https://mysecurekid.com/)** for the kid in terms of security and connectivity.

Here, the functionality of GPS tracking described below;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
dependencies {
    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'
    // Support Library
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
}
<fragment

        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

        android:id="@+id/map"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
```